# add an script tag in iframe whose content is getting set by srcdoc

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, script-tag

So What I want to do is something like this -
lets say I have an htmlString like this --

```
let htmlString = `<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

I want to modify this strings and add an -- another script tag as -- first script tag -- to get the output string as --

```
let htmlString = `<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="">console.log("Script Added at top")</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

**I don't know how many other tags will be there inside the head tag, so can't do a simple find and replace**

Answer (score 0):

DOME manipulation could work but you would never be able to insert your script as the first script to execute:

NOTE: This will not work in a stacksnippet - try it on your own server

```js
const html = `<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"><\/script>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = `console.log("Script Added at top")`;
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
const doc = iframe.contentWindow;
doc.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
```

You can remove the \ from /script if the script is external

```js
let html = `<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"><\/script>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`.split("\n")
html.splice(4,0,`    <script src="">console.log("Script Added at top")<\/script>`)
const htmlString = html.join("\n")
console.log(htmlString)
```

Insert before any script:

```js
let htmlString = `<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"><\/script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"><\/script>
  </head>
  <body>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80"/>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`
parts = htmlString.split("<script")
parts[0] += `    <script src="">console.log("Script Added at top")<\/script>\n     `;
htmlString = parts.join("<script")
console.log(htmlString)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the thing is I can't split on "\n" as there could be multiple tags in one line and I don't know how many other tags will be there inside the head tag.

Comment: See second version

Comment: Also you can insert after the title if you know title is always before any script

Comment: thanks again, but as I told Issue with all these is -- title -- might not be there, script might not be there,  first script might be writeen like -- "< script" (notice the space after -- < ) etc. thats why I don't want to rely on simple find and replace logic, rather I am looking for something related to DOM manipulation.

Comment: You cannot insert and run your script BEFORE the others have run if you want to first do DOM manipulation. If you do not mind being last, you can certainly do DOM manipulation

Comment: See my first example